# Javascript - cannot pass classes's function return into classes's variable

Tags: javascript, class, variables, this

I program usually in python and I am trying something that usually works in python. I have a function in a class. Its a callback function of mqtt library. What I want is to save the message(in a function onMessageArrived) that I receive into class variable called (this.)buffer.

```
class sub{
    constructor(hostname,port,clientid,topic){
        this.buffer = [];
        this.hostname=hostname;
        this.port=port;
        this.clientid = clientid;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(hostname,port, clientid);
        // set callback handlers
        this.client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
        this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived; <----Problem
        // connect the client
        this.client.connect({onSuccess:this.onConnect});

                                      }
    onConnect(){
          console.log('OnConnect');
    }

    onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
          if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
            console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
        }
        }

    onMessageArrived(message) {
          console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
          this.buffer.push(message.payloadString)   <-------------Problem

    }


    subs(){
        this.client.subscribe(this.topic)
    }
    publ(message){
        var mg = new Paho.MQTT.Message(message);
        mg.destinationName = this.topic;
        this.client.send(mg);
    }

    }
```

Problem is that function onMessageArrived doesnt push message into this.buffer variable-it looks like the function has no idea its inside class and therefore I cannot access class variable through 'this.'. In python it works this way. I am quite desperate because I looks to me like that function is totaly isolated and there is no other way than just print the message.

```
the error: 
onConnectionLost:AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message: Cannot read 
property 'push' of undefined, Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 
'push' of undefined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the problem is what `this` is inside an event handler ... try `this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived.bind(this)` ... or `this.client.onMessageArrived = (...args) => this.onMessageArrived(...args);`

Comment: both are correct @JaromandaX, why are you unsure? :)

Comment: I sometimes mess up arrow functions :p I have confirmed it's right now :p - haven't posted as an answer as I'm sure it's been asked/answered in detail before